# NodeJS socket.io change connection fast

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to implement a zero downtime socket.io cluster environment in NodeJS.
My goal is to distribute the server load in multiple node instances using Redis to sync data.

I was wounding if its possible, once a new change is detected, to make the socket.io client's reconnect on another instance without any down time or data loss.

To resume my idea, **my goal would be to reload socket.io with new code without any downtime.**

Comment: "reload socket.io with new code without any downtime"  What do you mean by this?

Comment: When I change my code, I would like to deploy it without dropping existing socket connections. My goal would be to give existing users the possibility to execute these new functionalities on there current socket connection.

Comment: Change what code?  You need to be much more specific.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a restful webservice this shouldn't be an issue. If you load balance your NodeJS servers and all the servers are connected to the same redis instance or cluster then when you gracefully pull a server out of your load balancers rotation there should be no noticeable downtime for your clients. Really this methodology would work for any environment.

Comment: The problem with this is that it works perfectly with HTTP requests but not with sockets. Sockets are always connected unlike HTTP requests. So if I kill a process and make a new one with the recent code, all connected users will loose there connection.

Comment: I think this issue will be resolved with good design. If your session is handled by redis, and a server goes down. The client side should be smart enough to know that the server went down. It should send a second request with a session id and the socket should easily be resolved from that point. There will of course be 'some' downtime but it would be very minimal. Unless you are constantly pinging the same server I don't see you getting around this though.

Comment: Ok, I guess this is the best solution. Use a load balancer with redis on the server and program the client socket.io to immediately reconnect and pass session information. Thanks for the help ;)